# Windows shortcut to run a Git Bash script

Tags: windows, shell, desktop, msysgit, git-bash

Assuming I have a test.sh script that runs a server and Git Bash installed, how do I create a Windows shortcut that I can double click to run tesh.sh in Git Bash in the foreground and allows me to see the output of the server?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Git bash is already a batch file with content similar to this :

```
C:\WINNT\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"
```

If you want **run (and leave running) a shell script** in the context of the shell, specify it at the command line. The trick is that when the script file name is interpreted, it uses the *Windows path*, not the equivalent path in the sh/Git environment.

In other words, to run the file `D:\temp\test.sh` in the Git shell and leave it running, create this batch file :

```
C:\WINNT\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -- D:\temp\test.sh"
```

On the other hand, if you want to **run a script and get your shell back**, you should :

1. Open the shell as is
2. Edit or create `~/.profile` (try `vi ~/.profile`)
3. Add this line : `~/test.sh` (ajdust the path if needed)

So with a `.profile` that looks like this :

```
echo Executing .profile
/bin/sh ~/test.sh
```

And `test.sh` that looks like this :

```
echo Hello, World!
```

You will get this prompt :

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.7.11-preview20120710)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
Executing .profile
Hello, World!

ixe013@PARALINT01 ~
$
```

Comment: Awesome, after I revised the question, I realized I didn't need it to return to the Gish Bash shell prompt after executing the script.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the four lines "Welcome to Git ..." at the beginning?

Comment: For many it'll be `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -- D:\temp\test.sh"`

Comment: Using `-i` while also specifying a script to execute is mostly pointless - the `bash` instance will _not_ stay open, and to the script it will look like it's being run in an interactive shell, which is irrelevant at best, and can result in different behavior at worst.
You should make it clearer that your profile-based solution will invoke the script for _all_ future login shells, which may be undesired.

Comment: Also, by running the script in a regular console window that defaults to the Windows OEM code page, you may run into character encoding issues.

Comment: Leaving the other issues aside, there is no need for an intermediate batch file;  a _shortcut file_, as requested by the OP, can use this command directly (`cmd.exe` needn't be involved): `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" -l D:\temp\test.sh`

Answer (score 36):

Other answers work, but there is a shorter solution, that fully answers the **question**, which was:

> How to create a Windows shortcut that I can double click to run
>   `tesh.sh` in Git Bash

The **answer** is: add the following command to the `Target:` field of the shortcut:

```
"C:\Git\bin\sh.exe" -l "D:\test.sh"
```

[image]

Where, `-l` is the short for `--login`.

To better understand what this command does, consult with official GNU docs about [Invoking Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash):

> - `-l` (`--login`): Make this shell act as if it had been directly invoked by    login. When the shell is interactive, this is equivalent
>     to starting    a login shell with `exec -l bash`. When the shell is
>     not interactive,    the login shell startup files will be executed.
>     `exec bash -l` or    `exec bash --login` will replace the current
>     shell with a Bash login    shell.

Also note that:

- You either need the full path to `sh.exe` or have it in your `PATH` environment variable (as others have already pointed out).
- If you really need to force shell invocation in interactive mode, you can add the `-i` option
- The last parameter is the path to the script that has to be executed. This path should be in Windows format.

Comment: +1 Perfect. Just one additional advice: Save your \*.sh script as UTF-8 (**no** `Windows 1252` like notepad does and **no** `UTF8-BOM` like Visual Studio does!)

Comment: Note that this will automatically close the window when the script terminates, so your answer doesn't satisfy the "allows me to see the output of the server" requirement. Also, by running the script in a regular console window that defaults to the Windows OEM code page, you may run into character encoding issues.

Answer (score 11):

Best solution in my opinion:

- Invokes the right shell
- No unnecessary windows
- Invokes a bash script afterwards
- Window will stay open after the script exits

Do the following:

1. **Create a shortcut** to `mintty.exe` on your desktop, for example. It is found under `%installation dir%/Git/usr/bin/mintty.exe`
2. **Edit properties** of the shortcut and change the target (keep the path):

`"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe" -h always /bin/bash -l -e 'D:\folder\script.sh'`

---

Explanation of the parameters:

`-h always` keeps the window open when the script finished, so the window won’t disappear while you are still reading the output (remove if you don’t need to read the output and want the window to close automatically).

`-l` makes this shell act as if it had been directly invoked by login.

`-e` exits immediately if a pipeline returns a non-zero status ([more info](https://superuser.com/questions/729565/bin-bash-e-what-is-e-other-arguments)).

Comment: Nice. And if necessary, remember to set "Start in" - the current directory when the script runs.

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend to use environment variable `%ComSpec%`, instead of absolute path to `cmd`:

```
%ComSpec% /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"
```

or even just `cmd` command, which is usually available from *%PATH%*:

```
cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"
```

if your `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` added to `PATH` (which is also common solution and one of cases on *TortoiseGit* installing) you can use just:

```
cmd /c "sh --login -i"
```

Comment: I had to use cmd.exe (with the .exe extension), otherwise, it would not run.

Comment: check your PATHEXT environmen varialbe, it should be something like this .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

Comment: `PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW`

Comment: If you create a _shortcut file_ as requested by the OP, `cmd.exe` needn't be involved at all.