# Git and Batch file

Tags: git, batch-file

I want to start an application right after `git` loads in a Windows batch file.

**I normally use:**

```
node server.js
```

**How do I incorporate that into:**

```
start "" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your command in [your `~/.profile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/415444/6309).
You can see a full example in "[Windows shortcut to run git bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21580885/6309)":

> On the other hand, if you want to run a script and get your shell back, you should :
>
> - Open the shell as is
> - Edit or create `~/.profile` (try `vi ~/.profile`)
> - Add this line : `~/test.sh` (adjust the path if needed)

In `test.sh`, you can add any command you want, like `node server.js` (or you could add them directly in the `.profile`)