# VS Code Git push is not pushing the code to remote

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I cloned a GIT repo in my device and started editing the code using VSCode. Then I made several changes to my code and committed it successfully.

But when I tried to push it from push menu it doesn't seem to be working. It *shows* that it's *syncing*, but that goes on forever.

I couldn't find any settings to configure credentials of git.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do git push in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993599/how-to-do-git-push-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I had this same issue, rebooting fixed it for me.  Also I've heard from VSCode GitHub forums that uninstalling git, rebooting, and then reinstalling git works.

Comment: You can troubleshoot the exact issue by opening View > Output, then selecting Git in the dropdown on the right of the Output panel. You will probably see the relevant error message from git.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all check whether you have already configured GIT on environment variables. If so, simply run below commands on VS Code terminal

```
$>git --version
```

Expected output

> git version 2.28.0.windows.1

Use the command below to avoid prompt of git credentials every time and set it at global level

```
$>git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

This will push your code to git repository

```
$>git push origin master
```

Try again, with push menu on VS Code.

Hope that helps !

Comment: Did not work for me

Comment: I have auth set up via an SSH key from KeePassXC. If the KeePassXC database auto-locked after a period of inactivity, the push obviously doesn't succeed because it can't get the SSH key. However, VS Code doesn't report any error when trying to push in this situation. In VS Code Output, selecting Git in the dropdown, I can see the expected `> git push -u origin my-branch ... [info] git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).` but it's not highlighted as an error. Is this a bug in VS Code? I would expect an error message is in order in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I was just experiencing something *similar*. Although the issue OP describes is the push continuing to sync but failing to connect, in what sounds like an initial commit. In my case it appeared as though all pushes were successful, in an existing repo/project where I've never had issues, nor had to do any initial git configurations inside VS... Things have always just worked, until the past few days, I just noticed none of my pushes actually made it to the repo.

But the title of the post is still relevant, so I'll answer in case it helps anyone else:

A simple VS Code update fixed my issue. While troubleshooting, I noticed a notification on the gear icon in the bottom left - which was an update ready to install. Once the update was installed and VS code restarted, I tried another pull, and then a push and everything's back to normal. Three commits finally found their way to the repo.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem with an existing and previously used repo, after a complete re-installation of my Windows and the development tools. It was may be due to changes with the way authentication is now handled by Git (Git Credential Manager?, as I noticed during installation).

Anyway, to solve it, I had to manually run:

```
git push
```

It asked me for an authentication option, and once I selected it and completed it, VS Code sync is now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps

1. reset your commit using- git reset HEAD~1
2. take a pull - git pull

if the pull is unsuccessful then use - git stash

3. commit your changes again
4. Try to push your commit

Make sure you are connected to your git repository (any missing lan or wifi conenction)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and was hoping to give a little more insight, as my vscode was stock and I ran into this problem right after cloning a repo. I would first recommend [tig](https://jonas.github.io/tig/INSTALL.html), as I was able to get more information on the problem rather than just try anything that came up on SO.

When I first used tig, I found that when I said commit with vscode via the check mark, it seemed to show up and have a commit, but didn't show up on GitHub.com. I then realized that vscode doesn't actually push the code with the check mark button, and you have to open a terminal either in vscode or the folder and actually `git push origin main`.

I recommend tig because in another similar problem I was pushing to different refs than main, which were only found with tig.