# modify local branch base on origin/master will affect local master branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout, git-remote

I have created a branch named `test` based on the `origin/master` branch, then I made some changes to the test branch, I found out the same modification also appeared on the local master branch, is it normal?

Or What should I do to avoid this situation happen again，should I create a branch base on another remote branch?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: It sounds like you didn't checkout or switch to the new branch before committing. If you had the master would not have been affected

Comment: Time to check the branch that you have checked out with `git status` or `git btranch`.

Comment: Can you share how you have created your test branch, commit change to it and switch back to master ?

Comment: My git command is `git checkout -b test origin/master`, I haven't commit the modification yet

Comment: If you haven't committed, then the claim "the same modification also appeared on the local master branch" is false. Your "modification" is not "on" _any_ branch. It's just some stuff hanging around in your working tree.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67450004/git-checkout-branch-after-git-add-seems-not-update-index-and-working-area See my answer there, which explains why uncommitted changes remain in the working tree when you switch branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My git command is git checkout -b test origin/master

Do not use the [old and confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) command [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), but, since Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) the [`git switch` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch).

Any modified files in the index (`git add`) would still be there when switching branch. If you don't want that:

- either git switch to your previous branch (`git switch -`) and commit there.
- or [`git stash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70855157/6309) those changes.