# How can I git stash a specific file?

Tags: git, git-stash

How can I stash a specific file leaving the others currently modified out of the stash I am about to save?

For example, if git status gives me this:

```
younker % gst      
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   app/controllers/cart_controller.php
#   modified:   app/views/cart/welcome.thtml
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

and I only want to stash app/views/cart/welcome.thtml, how would I do that? Something like (but of course this does not work):

```
git stash save welcome_cart app/views/cart/welcome.thtml
```

Comment: The "possible duplicate" question currently has an incorrect answer marked as accepted.

Comment: you can use `git checkout -- filename` and revert it to the original state.

Comment: @visualex it will indeed revert it, but not stash it

Comment: Re Penguin Brian's comment: Yes, the accepted answer to the "possible duplicate" question links to this question for recent versions of git.

Comment: $ git stash -- filename.ext

Answer (score 3367, accepted):

**EDIT:** Since git 2.13, there is a command to save a specific path to the stash: `git stash push <path>`. For example:

```
git stash push -m welcome_cart app/views/cart/welcome.thtml
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

You can do that using `git stash --patch` (or `git stash -p`) -- you'll enter interactive mode where you'll be presented with each hunk that was changed. Use `n` to skip the files that you don't want to stash, `y` when you encounter the one that you want to stash, and `q` to quit and leave the remaining hunks unstashed.  `a` will stash the shown hunk and the rest of the hunks in that file.

Not the most user-friendly approach, but it gets the work done if you really need it.

Comment: The only thing this doesn't seem to do is include changes to binary filed. I edited some graphics, did the git stash --patch method and they were never listed.

Comment: Cumbersome, but works.  I wish there was a quick way to stash only staged changes, and then have the changes go into the unstaged working tree when it's later popped.

Comment: @JamesJohnston `git stash --keep-index` will allow you to stash all the unstaged changes (the opposite of what you're looking for). http://stackoverflow.com/a/8333163/378253

Comment: If you say `a` instead of `y` it will stash that hunk + the remainder of the file, which is much faster.

Comment: @jeffamaphone great! also `d` will do the opposite, i.e. not stash any further hunks in the current file. and indeed `?` will show all possible options.

Comment: @svick, it got stuck when `git push -p`, no response.

Comment: Thanks!

[Command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) that I used is: `git stash save --patch "Stash message"`, which then I entered the [**Interactive Mode**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add.html) to select the hunks that I will stash.

I could also use this command: `git stash save --patch --no-keep-index "Stash message"` when I already staged the files I wanted to stash and doesn't want to keep it in after stashing.

Comment: `--patch` **is** user friendly!

Comment: @NicolasWormser `git stash --keep-index` is broken. Read the comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8333163/711807).

Comment: @svick How can i `git stash -p` with newly staged files (e. g. `new file:  test.txt`).

Comment: I wanted to use this but give the Stash a name. The order of parameters is quite sensitive - e.g. neither of `git stash -p save "name"` nor `git stash save "name" -p` worked but finally found that **`git stash save -p "name"`** *did* work.

Comment: @ZimbiX If you think you have a better answer, I think you should post an answer to the question this one is marked as duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040833/stash-only-one-file-out-of-multiple-files-that-have-changed-with-git), not edit mine.

Comment: @svick Sorry, I thought it was important information to include and didn't have the reputation to comment yesterday.

Comment: So yeah, I've posted those details now [in an answer to the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42942825/1239774).

Simply put, `git stash -p` does not support untracked files. [This simple script in my answer to another more specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42916031/1239774) allows you to specify which files to commit, **supports both tracked and untracked files**, and is easier for frequent use.

Comment: The edit in v2.13 is EXACTLY what this question requires.

Comment: also `-u` option allows to stash new, not already committed, file

Comment: Try this command:
`git stash push -- path/to/file.py`

Comment: if it's a new file, add the `--include-untracked` option like this `git stash push --include-untracked path/to/file.py`

Comment: What does `-m` do ?

Comment: @Vencovsky It stands for "message" and is used to specify optional description of the stash. If you don't need that, you can leave the `-m welcome_cart` part out.

Comment: FYI, popping this stashed file is done the same way as usual, git stash pop

Comment: @svick Might be worth updating the answer to clarify what the `-m` is doing, I (wrongly) assumed that you were listing different file paths after that, and so my path ended up getting added as a message instead of part of the stash :)

Comment: No one got an equivalent for this for 2.7.4? :(

Comment: This also works for multiple files: `git stash push -m temp /file/one /file/two /file/three`

Comment: in Sourcetree app, you can leave the target files in "Unstaged files" and do "Stash Changes..." command, make sure check "Keep staged changes".

Answer (score 391):

I usually add to index changes I don't want to stash and then stash with `--keep-index` option.

```
git add app/controllers/cart_controller.php
git stash --keep-index
git reset
```

The last step is optional, but usually, you want it.  It removes changes from the index.

---

**Warning**
As noted in the comments, `git stash --keep-index` pushes everything onto the stash, both staged and unstaged. The `--keep-index` just leaves the index alone after the stash is done. This can cause merge conflicts when you later pop the stash.

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer if you have a lot changes you don't want to wade through with the --patch option.

Comment: No, this puts everything into the stash, both staged and unstaged. The `--keep-index` just leaves the index alone after the stash is done. So this isn't a valid answer to the question, AFAICT.

Comment: See my answer on @Rachel's question for a solution to doing the inverse of this (stashing the staged changes, instead of the unstaged changes) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040833/how-to-stash-only-one-file-out-of-multiple-files-that-have-changed/17137669#17137669

Comment: After, if you want to get back the files you stashed without committing the files you added, you can run `git stash; git stash pop stash@{1}`.

Comment: WARNING: Take note of @Raman's point. This doesn't do what it should. This will put the same changes in the stash **and** leave them in the working tree. When you later try to pop the stash, you are likely to get merge conflicts, and they are often really confusing and hard to fix.

Comment: @DanBerindei The staged files stayed in the index **and** went in the stash. If you edit one of them and try to unstash, you will often get an edit conflict. If you discard the changes to those files and unstash, the changes will come back - at least that's what happened last time I tried it.

Answer (score 286):

For stashing one file:

```
git stash -- filename.txt
```

To give a message in the command rather than enter it when prompted, add -m before the file part, e.g. `git stash -m "stash-message" -- filename1.txt`

For stashing more than one file:

```bash
git stash -m "stash-message" -- filename1.txt filename2.txt…
```

Comment: This only works for tracked files, otherwise you get an error like: `error: pathspec 'filename1' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Comment: this one worked fine with tracked files.+1, worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me as the fastest and simplest solution to OP's problem, +1

Comment: For stashing with a message add `-m` before file part, e.g. `git stash -m "your message" -- filename1.txt filename2.txt`

Comment: You can also stash untracked files by adding them to the staging area, e.g., `git add my.file` and then `git stash -- my.file`. And whenever you apply the stash changes, if you want, you can unstage them, so they remain untracked again.

Comment: Did not work on centos7 git version 1.8.3.1

Comment: What exactly does the `--` represent here? Is it some type of convention specific to git or something more general?

Comment: Simplest and best solution.

Comment: @Bower `--` means treat everything that follows me as a filename.

Answer (score 182):

To add to svick's answer, the `-m` option simply adds a message to your stash, and is entirely optional. Thus, the command

```
git stash push [paths you wish to stash]
```

is perfectly valid. So for instance, if I want to only stash changes in the `src/` directory, I can just run

```
git stash push src/
```

Comment: NB: Popping is done _without_ the path, just `git stash pop`.

Comment: This command is much more efficient than the `--keep-index` suggestion above which requires multiple commands, and is a bit counter-intuitive (adding the files you **don't** want to stash).

Answer (score 52):

If you are using visual studio code there is a simpler way to stash selected files.

1. Make sure you have installed [GitLens](https://gitlens.amod.io/) extension in VSCode
2. Go to Source Control tab
3. Select files those you want to stash
4. Right click on it, you will see many options. Click on **Stash Changes**

[image]

4. Now it will ask you to add some stash message. Add understandable message and hit enter.

[image]

Comment: mine shows: discard changes, stage changes, add to gitignore. Not stash

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere try using GitLens extension

Comment: great solution for many users of vscode, no need to fiddle with commands

Answer (score 24):

Short and Simple solution:

```
git stash -- filename.ext
```

in your case `git stash --  app/views/cart/welcome.thtml`

Comment: What version of git supports this? I'm on 2.1.4, and it's not supported.

Comment: Hi @JellicleCat I am using 2.31.1

Comment: if want to add comment : git stash push -m 【comment】 --  【file path】

Answer (score 13):

- **git status**
  (make sure your changes that can stash)

> src/config/bl.go

> src/config/dl.go

If you want to stash only dl.go

- **git stash push -m "< enter your msg eg:dl files reverted> " src/config/dl.go**

Show your stash list

- **git stash list**

Then checkout your branch and apply stash

- **git stash apply stash{0}**

Answer (score 7):

If you're OK with using a GIT GUI client, [Fork](https://fork.dev/) can pretty seamlessly do this as of May 2020. A GIF of the partial stash functionality will show this better than any words: [image: GIF of partial stash functionality in git-fork]

Note that Fork (which is a difficult name to Google for!) is not free software and costs $50 after the evaluation period, but you can just ignore the popups like you do for WinRAR or WinZip.

Answer (score 7):

Since git `2.35.0` you can stash staged changes using `--staged | -S` flag.

For instance:

```
git stash --staged
```

> --staged
>
> This option is only valid for push and save commands.
>
> Stash only the changes that are currently staged. This is similar to basic git commit except the state is committed to the stash instead of current branch.
>
> The --patch option has priority over this one.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash/2.35.0#Documentation/git-stash.txt---staged

The nice part about this new feature is that not only it's possible to stash specific untracked files, but also it's possible to stash specific part of the code changes in tracked files; when you add those to stage using `--patch | -p` flag.

Answer (score 5):

1. stage the changes you do NOT want to stash.
2. stash the remaining unstaged files with:

```
$ git stash save <give_it_a_name> --keep-index
```

The unstaged files are now stashed.
See the stash list with your named stash:

```
$ git stash list

stash@{0}: On mybranch: WIP220412-1119am
stash@{1}: On mybranch: WIP220312-749am
```

To restore the stashed files:

```
$ git stash apply stash@{<index_of_saved_stash>}
$ git stash apply stash@{0}
```

The changes stashed in WIP220412-1119am are now restored.
And the stash list remains as well, (instead of "git stash pop", you can retain the list this way.)

Comment: This only works for changed files I guess? If you want to add a new file to a stash you need to stage it first, which doesn't work with the `--keep-index` flag.

Answer (score 5):

@svick has posted a great answer. I wanted to stash all my .java files and leave build.gradle untouched so I ran:

```
git stash push *.java
```

Answer (score 4):

My preferred method (the easiest in my opinion) is simply:

`git stash -- <path/to/directory>`

or

`git stash -- path/to/directory/file.py`

Answer (score 2):

### I think using `git stash push <path>` will be nice! it also supports patterns.

- eg. `git stash push welcome.*ml` will stash any start with `welcome.` and end with `ml` files. This is suitable for you.

Comment: This also supports multiple paths inline.

Comment: @MohammadAbdurraafay add some inline example.

Answer (score -1):

In Source Control tab of vs-code, hold shift key and then select the files you want to stash, then right click and choose stash changes option.

Comment: This is the same as Akshay's answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/68377913/821832) but his has more details.