# In PhpStorm, can I stash only part of my changes?

Tags: git, phpstorm, git-stash

I read this question: [how can I git stash a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506339/how-can-i-git-stash-a-specific-file)

so i know i can use `git stash push <path>` or `git stash --patch` from the console, but i was wondering if maybe PhpStorm has a friendlier UI for stashing only selected parts of my changes (something like the interface when committing).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 6):

No, it cannot stash individual files. But if you really want to use the IDE, they have something similar called [Shelving](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html).

It is similar with stashing, but you cannot use it outside the IDE, git is not aware of it. But with it you can achieve what you are looking for.