# git diff file against its last change

Tags: git, git-diff

Is it possible to get git to produce a diff between a specific file as it exists now, and as it existed before the last commit that changed it?

That is, if we know:

```
$ git log --oneline myfile
123abc Fix some stuff
456def Frobble the foos
789dba Initial commit
```

Then `git diff 456def myfile` shows the last change to myfile. Is is possible to do the same without the knowledge produced by the `git log`; what changed in 123abc?

Comment: I prefer using `git diff HEAD^ <file_path>`

Comment: @asgs - Doesn't do what I was asking (for two reasons - `HEAD^` is `123abc`, `HEAD^^` is `456def`; and if there were other commits _that didn't affect this file_ then `HEAD^` refers to them)

Comment: You're right, missed the "the last commit that changed it" part

Answer (score 274, accepted):

This does exist, but it's actually a feature of `git log`:

```
git log -p [-m] [--follow] [-1] <path>
```

Note that `-p` can also be used to show the inline diff from a single commit:

```
git log -p -1 <commit>
```

Options used:

- `-p` (also `-u` or `--patch`) is hidden deeeeeeeep in the `git-log` man page, and is actually a display option for `git-diff`. When used with `log`, it shows the patch that would be generated *for each commit*, along with the commit information—and *hides* commits that do not touch the specified `<path>`. (This behavior is described in the paragraph on `--full-diff`, which causes the full diff of each commit to be shown.)
- `-m` causes merge commits to include the diff content (otherwise these just show the commit message, as if `-p` were not specified).
- `-1` shows *just* the most recent change to the *specified file* (`-n 1` can be used instead of `-1`); otherwise, *all* non-zero diffs of that file are shown.
- `--follow` is required to see changes that occurred prior to a rename.

As far as I can tell, this is the only way to immediately see the last set of changes made to a file without using `git log` (or similar) to either count the number of intervening revisions or determine the hash of the commit.

To see older revisions changes, just scroll through the log, or specify a commit or tag from which to start the log. (Of course, specifying a commit or tag returns you to the original problem of figuring out what the correct commit or tag is.)

Credit where credit is due:

- I discovered `log -p` thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14468031/1858225).
- Credit to FranciscoPuga and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5493663/1858225) for showing me the `--follow` option.
- Credit to ChrisBetti for mentioning the `-n 1` option and atatko for mentioning the `-1` variant.
- Credit to sweaver2112 for getting me to actually read the documentation and figure out what `-p` "means" semantically.
- Credit to Oscar Scholten for pointing out that by default, `-p` does not show diff-contents for merge commits.

Comment: This was a great solution for me. Showed each commit and its differences to the current file when I ran `git log -p filename`

Comment: Perfect. To see just the last change, it's as simple as adding the `-n 1` parameter. `git log -p -n 1 filename`

Comment: @ChrisBetti Thanks; I've incorporated that into my answer!

Comment: `-n 1` can also be replaced by `-1`, it doesn't change the result I just prefer the syntax: `git log -p -1 filename`

Comment: i really wish people would explain flags (-p) in their answers. (it means "show patch" which is like a diff with only the changed lines)

Comment: @sweaver2112 As you can tell from the answer itself, I'm happy to incorporate new information into my answer from helpful comments. Instead of complaining, why not suggest an improvement? You can even just edit the answer.

Comment: @kylestrand I'm with sweaver2112 on wishing folks would explain flags.  I'm trying to understand the `[--follow]` option, and I went to the link provided and nowhere can I find any input from FranciscoPuga as mentioned.  So, Kyle, what is the `--follow` option, what does it do, why was it recommended?

Comment: @zipzit I did say what it does: it shows changes prior to a rename. If you don't understand what I mean by this, then make a couple of commits that change a file, then rename it, then run the command (without `-1`) with and without `--follow`.

Comment: It does look like I linked to the wrong answer, though. I've fixed it; the answer in the corrected link explains the option.

Comment: there is a useful option "--skip=[n]". You can type `git log -p -1 --skip=1 <path>` to display second commit.

Comment: If the last commit is a merge commit, `git log -p -1 <path>` prints the commit message, not the diff. To get the diff, run `git log --first-parent -p -1 <path>`

Comment: @OscarScholten That's a good catch, but it's not `--first-parent` you need, it's `-m`. I'll update the answer; thanks!

Answer (score 236):

One of the ways to use git diff is:

```
git diff <commit> <path>
```

And a common way to refer one commit of the last commit is as a relative path to the actual HEAD. You can reference previous commits as HEAD^ (in your example this will be 123abc) or HEAD^^ (456def in your example), etc ...

So the answer to your question is:

```
git diff HEAD^^ myfile
```

Comment: Oh, of course. I tried `HEAD^`, but of course that produced nothing. Didn't think to try `HEAD^^`.

Comment: Maybe easier syntax for long-ago commits : `HEAD~2`

Comment: It is not true (at least for Git 1.9.0) that `HEAD^^ myfile` will actually refer to the second-to-last commit that changed `myfile`; it will refer to the second-to-last commit overall. Is there any way to specify "I want to see the last change made to this file" without either specifying (part of) the commit hash or counting the number of commits between the last change made to *that file* and the current revision?

Comment: Hm, looks like `git log -p` is pretty close.

Comment: @KyleStrand as you wrote `git log` is the way to go. But see [this answer also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5493663/930271)

Comment: @ibizaman cool! I put this at `git gui` tool add `git difftool -d HEAD~$ARGS`, thx!

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting fatal: bad revision '^^HEAD' ?? I'm running from the root directory that I cloned and using the fully qualified path to the file name. git status works fine and showed me all my changed files. and then I ran git add *.java and then git commit but I want to diff all my files so I can create a meaningful commit message.

Comment: Use HEAD^^ not ^^HEAD or try using HEAD~2

Comment: downvote reason: the question asks "between a specific file as it exists now, and as it existed before _the last commit that changed it_", but if the file was not changed in the last overall commit, this answer does not work.

Comment: Why is this upvoted? It it no way answers the question asked >:(

Comment: @gman For two years it was the only answer, and it was presumably "close enough" to what a lot of people were looking for.

Comment: @KyleStrand kind of strange/amazing that a question like this took two whole years to answer. also strange that the "close enough" but... IMO wrong answer got soo many upvotes.

Comment: And if you are using meld as difftool: `git difftool HEAD^ file`

Comment: As noted in previous comment under this answer it is not a correct answer to the posted question.

Answer (score 9):

If you are fine using a graphical tool this works very well:

```
gitk <file>
```

gitk now shows all commits where the file has been updated. Marking a commit will show you the diff against the previous commit in the list. This also works for directories, but then you also get to select the file to diff for the selected commit. Super useful!

Comment: Also very useful: `git difftool HEAD^ file` or `git difftool -d HEAD^ path`