# Shorthand to view diff of previous version of file

Tags: git, diff

I can easily find out what changed for a file since the last commit with `git diff HEAD^ -- <filename>` but *is there an equivalent shorthand to view a diff for a particular file since it was last committed*, regardless of how many commits have happened since?  Or to go back N commits of that particular file?

**Context:** I found an error in a file and I want to track down when it snuck in.  It's easy enough to get a log report for a particular file with `git log -<n> <filename>` to show only the commits that included changes to that file.  So clearly I can just copy and paste the SHAs from that `log` report, but what I really want is to be able to do something like `git diff ^ -- <filename>` or `git diff ~2 -- <filename>`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want `git blame`?

Answer (score 43):

```
$ git log -p <filename>
```

will show you the log message plus a diff for each commit that touched the named file.

To show only differences to the previous version, ask for just one step in log history:

```
$ git log -1 -p <filename>
```

Comment: I find it odd that this seems to be the closest thing to what OP is looking for, but it's quite useful nevertheless. Thanks.

Comment: @MattMcHenry Really nice. I edited your answer and added syntax for showing just change in last commit, as asked in OP.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `git log` formatting to get the hashes of previous commits to a file. For example,

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h' -1 --skip=1 <filename>
```

will get you the 2nd to last commit to touch a specific file. In fact, if you don't specify a filename, this will get you the 2nd to last commit on the entire repository. To get older hashes, you might set up a git alias that calls a shell function, like this:

```
[alias]
    prior-hash = "!ph() { git log --pretty=format:'%h' -1 --skip=$1 $2; }; ph"
```

To use it, you'd type something like `git prior-hash n <filename>`, where n is the (n+1)th most recent version of the file. So 1 would be the 2nd to last commit to the file, 2 would be the 3rd to last, etc, and 0 would be the most recent commit to touch that file. And again, the filename is optional, if you want to examine the repo as a whole.

I'm sure you could figure out how to build a diff command from there:

```
[alias]
    prior-hash = "!ph() { git log --pretty=format:'%h' -1 --skip=$1 $2; }; ph"
    diff-prev-easy = "!dp() { git diff $(git prior-hash $1 $2).. $2; }; dp"
```

which would be used similar to the prior-hash alias, `git diff-prev-easy n <filename>`. This would compare the (n+1)th last revision to the most recent revision of the file. If you wanted to instead compare the (n+1)th last revision to the nth last revision, it's a simple change:

```
[alias]
    prior-hash = "!ph() { git log --pretty=format:'%h' -1 --skip=$1 $2; }; ph"
    diff-prev = "!dp() { git diff $(git prior-hash $1 $2)..$(git prior-hash $(($1 - 1)) $2) $2; }; dp"
```

which, again, is used the same way: `git diff-prev n <filename>`

One potential problem to watch out for, though, is that `git log` lists commits in chronological order, which may not be what you want. Consider this history:

```
1 - 2 - - - 4 - 5   master
      \       /
        3 - -       develop
```

Our `git diff-prev 1` command would produce the diff between commit 4 and 5, as expected. But `git diff-prev 2` would show the diff between commit 3 and 4, which is likely undesirable.

Comment: I don't know about the OP, but this is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`git blame` should get you to your destination pretty fast.