# Switch branches and take only specific changes with you

Tags: github, branch

I’m still fairly new to the Git way of thinking, and I use it almost exclusively through the VSCode GUI and the Github desktop application, so bear with me if my thinking or terminology is backwards or sideways.

I frequently find myself in the situation that I do some work, then realise some of the work I’ve just done should have been done in a different branch than I’m in and need to move those changes to another branch. But this only applies to some of the changes in the current branch – the rest of the changes in the branch do belong where they are and should stay put. Usually it’ll be just a small handful of files I want to move, while perhaps 40 or 50 files should stay where they are.

There are lots of questions and tutorials on how to change branches and move *all* your uncommitted changes to another branch; I can also find questions on how to cherry-pick from an existing commit (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/) – but Google as I might, I cannot find any descriptions of how to move only *specific, selected, uncommitted changes* to a different branch. That is,

- the changes are *not committed* in the current branch (and I don’t want to commit them there, because they don’t belong in that branch)
- the changes to move are only a *subset* of the total number of changes in the current branch
- after the move, the changes should *disappear* from the current branch and *be added to* existing changes in the other branch so that I can commit them in that branch

I can cherry-pick the files manually (file by file) or I can stage or unstage the particular changes I want to move or not move; either way is fine with me (or if there’s another way, that’d be fine too).

Theoretically, I would imagine I should be able to stash the changes in current branch *excluding* the files I want to move, and then switch to the other branch. I’ve found a description of [how to stash specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040833/), but not a way to do the opposite, stashing everything *except* specific files.

Is there some relatively simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, as always happens, a solution occurred to me right after posting here… Very possibly not the best or easiest way of doing it, but it works.

It can be done in a few, relatively simple steps combining staging and stashing:

1. Stage the changes you want to bring over to the other branch
2. Stash your unstaged changes with `git stash -ku` (`k` for keep-index, which [limits it to unstaged changes](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/8b32f1cf6b-stashing-only-unstaged-changes), `u` for including untracked files)
3. Switch to the branch you want and commit the changes there
4. Switch back to the branch you were in and apply/pop your stash with `git stash apply` `git stash pop`

For reasons I don’t really understand, the staged changes also reappeared when I applied my stash, but since they were now committed in the other branch, I could just unstage and discard them in the current branch.