# Toggle between multiple .env files like .env.development with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dotenv

There's a requirement to switch between production/development environment while app is running (in development mode). I'm using [react-native-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv) third-party in order to support .env files. I've found a solution that it's possible in nodejs environment like [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040833/how-do-i-stash-only-one-file-out-of-multiple-files-that-have-changed).
does anyone know that how is that possible in react native? or is there any other clean alternative?

Answer (score 4):

This feature is already built-in `react-native-dotenv`. Here is the precise [Link](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv#multi-env) for official documentation. In addition, it's completely up to you how you manage multiple .env files. You can use either [dotenv-flow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-flow) or [react-native-dotenv](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv).

Comment: Thank you so much, but the requirement is to switch between the .env files in run time (while app is running). is there any solution for that?

Comment: Do you want to change .env while the app is in the production phase like a signed APK or do you want to change it while app is connected to the local server?

Comment: No! (thanks for following). let me rephrase it again.
while the app is running in the development mode (like running via Expo go), I need to switch between the production and development environments (without restarting the bundler) so the testers can switch between them and test the app.

Comment: As far as I know, it's kind of impossible (at least for me) because every time we do a change in .env which is in .gitignore we have to tell the metro server manually to publish changes to the App. You could manipulate .env with a component that will change the required .env to `dev` or `prod` at run time via the toggle button in a separate screen(just for testing purposes). 
i.e
 `toggle===off ? setStates of dev : setStates of prod`